# How to control a bool individual to each instantiated script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want this script to check if bool is true and if it is then play an audio once but if its false then don't play the audio but the problem is that this script is in multiple gameobjects and is always constantly turning on and off so the bool may be true on this gameobject but false on the other and so when I tried checking the bool value it returns both true and false and so never really executing the if condition to play the music until both gameobjects meet the same condition...how do I fix this?

ps: the gameobject isn't a prefab

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (isChasing && inSightArea)
        {
            if (!enemyFOV.chaseSound.isPlaying)
            {
                Debug.Log("music playing");
                enemyFOV.chaseSound.Play();
            }

            Debug.Log(enemyFOV.chaseSound.isPlaying);
        }

        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("is patrolling");
            enemyFOV.chaseSound.Stop();
        }

    }
```

the "music playing" debug log seems to be logging at the right time i want but the enemyFOV.chaseSound.Play(); somehow didn't run at all until both bool from both object returns true for some reason..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your `enemyFOV` is the **same** instance for both your objects.

So if in one instance the `isChasing && inSightArea` is `true`, but on another it is not

=> The one object starts the sound, the other object stops the sound immediately.

---

I would rather store all currently chasing objects and let your `EnemyFOV` class control the sound like e.g.

```
public class EnemyFOV : MonoBehaviour
{
    // store all currently chasing instances
    private readonly HashSet<YourScript> currentlyChasing = HashSet<YourScript>();

    // your audiosource as you have it anyway
    public AudioSource chaseSound;

    // call this one instead
    public void SetChasing(YourScript yourScript, bool iAmChasing)
    {
        if(iAmChasing)
        {
            // Store this instance
            if(!currentlyChasing.Contains(yourScript)) currentlyChasing.Add(yourScript);
        }
        else
        {
            // remove this instance 
            if(currentlyChasing.Contains(yourScript)) currentlyChasing.Remove(yourScript);
        }

        // If there is at least one instance and no sound is playing
        if(currentlyChasing.Count > 0 && !chaseSound.isPlaying)
        {
            // -> start the sound
            Debug.Log("music playing");
            chaseSound.Play();
        }
        // If there is no chasing instance but sound is playing
        else if (currentlyChasing.Count == 0 && chaseSound.isPlaying)
        {
            // -> stop the sound
            chaseSound.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `YourScript` is the script from which you are calling your original code.

There instead you will now do

```
private void Update()
{
    enemyFOV.SetChasing(this, isChasing && inSightArea);
}
```